# why am I getting a ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero?

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple function that takes user input and uses it as a divisor for numbers to 100. Why am I getting a ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero?

```
def divisor():
    num = int(input('Please input a number. It will be used as a divisor. '))
    for i in range(0,100):
        if num%i == 0:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Your `i` starts from 0, so during the first iteration, it divides `num` by 0, which is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
def divisor():
    num = int(input('Please input a number. It will be used as a divisor. '))
    for i in range(1,100):
        if num%i == 0:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
num % 0
```

produces a ZeroDivisionError: integer division or **modulo by zero**. It's in the error statement. The value `i` in the for loop starts from 0, which is what is causing the error. The for loop should be:

```
for i in range(1,100):
```